# How to use Google Play pre-launch report with expo / react-native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo

Google has a built in app crawler for the app store called the pre-launch report.

It will crawl your app on a bunch of different devices and give you some basic feedback assuming you:

1. provide credentials (easy)
2. provide resource IDs for username / password fields, sign-in button (hard)

It doesn't appear to be trivial to set these to be static in expo / react-native, they are dynamically generated.

Is there a smart way to set this up?

Comment: The ability to add resource IDs is being tracked as a feature request/idea at https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-support-for-resource-id

Answer (score 1):

when you submit the app for any testing track, Google Play console will automatically add this version to "Pre-launch Report" and start testing automatically (almost randomly) on real devices. you don't have control over this.

but if you want more control over this process you could use [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/?authuser=0#implementation_paths) it uses the same concept as Google Play console "Pre-launch Report" but with more features.

Note: you can use this tool for free but eventually you may need to pay for it.